# Google chrome won't work Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome

When I type `google-chrome` in terminal I get the following error message

```
[20289:20289:0726/135341.575563:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

When I type `google-chrome --no-sandbox` I get the following error message

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[20448:20448:0726/135539.554130:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
```

I have tried reinstalling chrome.
I have also tried `rm -rf /home/USERNAME/.config/google-chrome/` and `rm -rf /home/kawish/.cache/google-chrome/`

`

Comment: Maybe the line in the sourcecode helps to find out: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/sandbox/linux/services/credentials.cc#119

Comment: Do `strace -e open $(type -p google-chrome)`, and see which file `open` fails with `-13`. It's a permissions/ownership problem.  Check with `ls -l` of that file. For a more detailed investigation, Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions but changing the kernel version did it for me.